# mathfrak in htlatex

Tags: amsmath, htlatex

In LaTeX `mathfrak` command is working fine and when using `htlatex` it's converting and not viewing in the `HTML file`. This is Bug in `htlatex`? My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{A}$
$\mathfrak{B}$
$\mathfrak{C}$
$\mathfrak{D}$
$\mathfrak{E}$
$\mathfrak{F}$
$\mathfrak{G}$
$\mathfrak{H}$
$\mathfrak{I}$
$\mathfrak{J}$
$\mathfrak{K}$
$\mathfrak{L}$
$\mathfrak{M}$
$\mathfrak{N}$
$\mathfrak{O}$
$\mathfrak{P}$
$\mathfrak{Q}$
$\mathfrak{R}$
$\mathfrak{S}$
$\mathfrak{T}$
$\mathfrak{U}$
$\mathfrak{V}$
$\mathfrak{W}$
$\mathfrak{X}$
$\mathfrak{Y}$
$\mathfrak{Z}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get exactly same output as with `pdflatex` with `htlatex`:

[image]

```xml
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="eufm-10">&#x1D504;</span> <span 
class="eufm-10">&#x1D505; &#x212D; &#x1D507; &#x1D508; &#x1D509; &#x1D50A; &#x210C; &image; &#x1D50D; &#x1D50E; &#x1D50F; &#x1D510; &#x1D511; &#x1D512; &#x1D513; &#x1D514; &real; &#x1D516; &#x1D517; &#x1D518; &#x1D519; &#x1D51A; &#x1D51B; &#x1D51C; &#x2128; </span>
```

Comment: i also getting same output. But its not showing in mozilla/google chrome browser.

Comment: @Balaji then you maybe doesn't have needed fonts installed on your system?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and could you please advise the required unicode font name in the Browser please...

Comment: @Balaji this depends on system you use, you can install additional fonts. see https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en for Windows setup